# Reactで可変長のinputを扱いたい

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

inputのvaluesを配列で保持するときに、どのinputの値が変化したのかをindexのようなものから取得して配列を更新するようにしなければならないと考えますが、そのようなことは可能でしょうか。コンポーネントのrender()は以下のとおりです。

```
  render(){
    var posList = this.state.query.pos.map((p) => {
      return (
        <TextField
          key={p}
          value={p}
          onChange={this.onQueryChanged}
          disabled={this.state.loading}
        />
      );
    });
    var negList = this.state.query.neg.map((n) => {
      return (
        <TextField
          key={n}
          value={n}
          onChange={this.onQueryChanged}
          disabled={this.state.loading}
        />
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <Col xs={12} md={6}>
          <p>Positive</p>
          {posList}
          <IconButton
            onClick={this.onAddPositive}
          >
            <FontIcon className="material-icons">add_circle</FontIcon>
          </IconButton>
        </Col>
        <Col xs={12} md={6}>
          <p>Negative</p>
          {negList}
          <IconButton
            onClick={this.onAddNegative}
          >
            <FontIcon className="material-icons">add_circle</FontIcon>
          </IconButton>
        </Col>
        <FlatButton
          label="Send"
          disabled={this.state.loading}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

`TextField`の`onChange`で配列を更新したいのですができますでしょうか。`onChange`のインタフェースは以下のとおりです。

```
onChange(event, value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextField`の`id`propを設定することで問題を解決できました。